# Expression of a multiple of 5

Tags: javascript, math

I think I have rather a simple question, I think...

I have this code

```
var resul = numCorrect+numIncorrect;
if (resul == 5){}
```

In place of 5 I want to have a multiple of 5 (5, 10, 15, 20) and so on. No 0!

I don't know how to express this in jquery. 5n doesn't work.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use operator `%`:

```
if (resul && resul%5 == 0) {
   //multiple of 5
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want 0, so you need to do this : `if (resul && resul%5 == 0)`

Comment: Thank you, Milind Anantwar and Karl-Andre Gagnon. Your solution works perfectly wel!!! Really appreciate your help! PS it is "she" :-)

Comment: @AleksandraChuprova:glad it helps. and sorry about he-she thing :)

Answer (score 0):

The modulus operator (%) gives the remainder after a number is divided is divided. Multiples of five will always give a modulus of 0. So you just have to check the modulus and exclude zero

```
if ((resul%5 == 0) && (resul !=0)) {
   //result is a multiple of 5
}
```